# How can I debug why memory is not allocated or the result of the allocation is not stored?

Tags: c, memory-management

I am building a finite element solver. The following are my structures.

```
// Describes the cartesian grid used in the problem
typedef struct
{
  int N;                            // Number of segments along each direction
  double lb_x;
  double ub_x;
  double lb_y;
  double ub_y;
  double h;                         // Max grid resolution
  double* grid_nodes_x;             // Partition in x direction
  double* grid_nodes_y;             // Partition in y direction
} grid;

// subdomain object is defined before this

// Domain object
typedef struct domain
{
  grid* cartesian_grid;              // Reference to the grid object
  vertex* vertices;                  // Array of all vertexes in the domain
  int subdomain_count_x;             // Subdomains in X direction
  subdomain* subdomains;             // List of all subdomains
  int** subdomain_vertex_map;        // Map of subdomain to vertices, gives the local vertex order for assembly
} domain;
```

Now, I am trying to allocate space for this `int** subdomain_vertex_map` field inside domain as below:

```
// Create one big domain
domain* build_cartesian_domain(grid* cartesian_grid, int subdomain_count_x)
{
  int i,j;
  domain* cartesian_domain;
  #define CGN (cartesian_grid->N + 1)
  cartesian_domain = (domain*) calloc(1, sizeof(cartesian_domain));
  cartesian_domain->cartesian_grid = cartesian_grid;
  cartesian_domain->subdomain_count_x = subdomain_count_x;
  cartesian_domain->subdomain_vertex_map = (int**) calloc(2, sizeof(int*));
  #define CDM (cartesian_domain->subdomain_vertex_map)
  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
    cartesian_domain->subdomain_vertex_map[i] = (int*) calloc(10, sizeof(int));
    for(j = 0; j < CGN*CGN; j++)
    {
      CDM[i][j] = -1;
    }
  }
  #undef CGN
  #undef CDM

  return cartesian_domain;
}
```

For the time being some of the sizes are hard-coded for illustration of the issue. The issue I have is that the memory is not getting allocated or is allocated but does not get stored in the array of double pointers `cartesian_domain->subdomain_vertex_map` as the gdb trace below shows:

```
Breakpoint 1, build_cartesian_domain (cartesian_grid=0x606010, subdomain_count_x=1) at domain.c:16
16    cartesian_domain = (domain*) calloc(1, sizeof(cartesian_domain));
(gdb) n
17    cartesian_domain->cartesian_grid = cartesian_grid;
(gdb) 
18    cartesian_domain->subdomain_count_x = subdomain_count_x;
(gdb) 
19    cartesian_domain->subdomain_vertex_map = (int**) calloc(2, sizeof(int*));
(gdb) 
21    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
(gdb) 
23      cartesian_domain->subdomain_vertex_map[i] = (int*) calloc(10, sizeof(int));
(gdb) 
24      for(j = 0; j < CGN*CGN; j++)
(gdb) p cartesian_domain->subdomain_vertex_map
$1 = (int **) 0x606700
(gdb) p cartesian_domain->subdomain_vertex_map[i]
$2 = (int *) 0x0
(gdb) p i
$3 = 0
(gdb)
```

Any thoughts on how I can debug this issue? Thanks!

Comment: why do you use `j < CGN*CGN;`, when the allocated length was `10`, not `CGN*CGN` ?

Comment: Well, like I said, 10 is for testing allocation. As you notice, I am not executing that line in gdb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dereference the pointer in order to get the size for `cartesian_domain` (and don't cast `calloc`)

```
cartesian_domain = (domain*) calloc(1, sizeof(cartesian_domain));
```

should be

```
cartesian_domain = calloc(1, sizeof(*cartesian_domain));
```

or

```
cartesian_domain = calloc(1, sizeof(domain));
```

> How can I debug why memory is not allocated or the result of the
>   allocation is not stored?

It is allocated but with a wrong size, take a look to [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: I'll try the suggestion although I think Cartesian domain is being allocated just fine. I am worried about cartesian_domain->subdomain_vertex_mapping [<some index>]

Comment: Yes, Valgrind is next on the list of things to try if the answer is not straightforward.

Comment: No, it's not allocated with the correct size, check it using `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(cartesian_domain));`, you will get `4` or `8` depending of `sizeof(pointer)` in your platform instead of `sizeof(domain)`.

Comment: Oops, it's a typo. I wanted to say size of(domain*), I just realized I typed sizeof(cartesian_domain). Thanks for pointing it out. But I will still try your solution

Comment: `sizeof(domain*)` is also wrong :), you want the size of the dereferenced pointer: `*cartesian domain` or the size of the `struct` itself: `sizeof(domain)`

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo again :), I'm typing from my phone. :D

Comment: @mod0 why are you typng on your phone?  What are you doing?  You are wasting everyone's time with the typos - please find a more suitable environment where you can copy/paste.

Comment: @Martin, thank you for your advice. For your clarification, the question was typed from the computer, where I copied and pasted my code, so that typo was real. The one with reference to my phone is my comment above. I was returning home when I wrote that. Do you have any other suggestions?